# Error while installing APEX : existing state of package "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY" has been invalidated

Tags: java, windows-10, oracle19c, oracle-apex-20.1

I was trying to install Apex in windows, when I faced this issue on execution of the below command.
`@apexins SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/`
The issue obtained is:

> not ok 5 - Installing Package Specs (Runtime)                       |   1.15
> # Message: ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded ORA-0406
> 1: existing state of package "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY" has been invalidate
> d
> # ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_
> SECURITY"
> # ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_200200.
> WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06512: at line 2
> #
> # Statement: begin
> #    wwv_flow_security.g_security_group_id := 10;
> # end;
> # Message: ORA-04061: existing state of package "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_SECURI
> TY" has been invalidated
> # ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_
> SECURITY"
> # ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_200200.
> WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06512: at line 2
> #
> # Statement: as above
> # Message: invalidated ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "
> APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_200200.
> WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06512: at line 2
> #
> # Statement: as above
> # Message: ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "APEX_200200.
> WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_200200.
> WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06512: at line 2
> #
> # Statement: as above
> # Message: "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY" ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find
> program unit being called: "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY"
> # ORA-06512: at line 2i